# Can VS 2019 now do async SSIS main?

Tags: c#, ssis, visual-studio-2019, ssis-2019

Using Visual Studio 2019 and a new SSIS project, is it now possible to use an async main method?  I can't set the C# version as SSIS makes class libraries so I'm not sure what to do to make sure it's enabled.